# Rails url constraint

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Im making a url pass in this date format at the very end of the string

```
2011-11-02T13:59:26.13Z
```

I can do this

```
a.sub!(/\..*/,'')
```

to knock off the .(digit)(digit)Z and work with the time in my controller.

if i put the time in regular format in my url, it works fine. If i put in the specified format above, i get a blank page. If i add the constraint i made (works fine with chopping the end off in the console, I get an routing (no route matches [GET] ...). What should I do to allow to pass in the date format i need (Im using rails 3 if thats important)

Answer (score 0):

The colon is a reseved character and cannot be used within a URL. See [RFC 2366 section 2.2](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html)

Also, the . (dot) is used to designate a format type in rails, so when this is passed into the router it will try to render a layout for the '13Z' format.

You should encode that time in another format that does not require these characters.

E.g.

`20111102135926`

Because each field is fixed width it is still easy to parse with a regex.

You could also atime which can be parsed directly in Ruby.